# Installer for WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, installation

I have a WCF service and I want to create an installer package for it. The service will be deployed on servers running either Windows 2003 or 2008 server. Can this be done with Visual Studio 2010 (Pro)? I need the installer to do the following during the installation process:

- Install dependencies
- Set and/or create the application pool in IIS
- Set other IIS configuration such as allowed page types, virtual directory, port, etc.
- Change web.config connection string during install

I imagine these operations would be done using some sort of scripting language, like VBscript? It would be cool to use F# -- not sure whats possible though. If not in Visual Studio 2010 are there other free tools that assist with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) which is an open source windows installer toolset that can do all of the things you mention.